# Java App installer and launcher for both Mac and Win?

Tags: java, macos, installation, launcher

I have a large Java app, with many required .jar files.
I'd like to build a native launcher and installer for it, to run it on both Mac and Win machines.
It looks like I can use Launch4J to create a .exe file launcher on Windows. (though it only wraps a single .jar, the others have to be available in the path.) Then use IzPack to create a runnable .jar file that will install the .exe and relevant .jar files into a directory.

How do I do the same for OS/X?

Comment: izPack is cross platoform, but the application structure isn't, that is, by convention, Windows likes programs in `Program Files` and Mac OS require applications to be bundled into `.app`s and stored in either the `Application` folder or the user's `Application` folder, so providing a single installer to do both may be problematic.  A better solution might be to provide bundles for both platforms

Answer (score 1):

After more digging, and avoiding all the dead URL's I found, I've come up with:

A) Use Launch4J to build a .exe for Windows systems.

B) Use AppBundler (from java.com) to build a App Bundle for OS/X.

IzPack can be used to make an installer for either platform.